# Can I download a pdf file right after I generate it in a model action in before_save callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, model

In the model, I generate a pdf file, if payment method is Invoice:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  require 'prawn'

  after_save :generate_pdf

  def generate_pdf
      if payment_method.name == 'Invoice'
        pdf = Prawn::Document.generate("public/pdf/invoice_#{SecureRandom.hex}_#{user.name}_№#{id}.pdf",
                               page_size: [200, 500],
                               page_layout: :landscape,
                               margin: 10) do |pdf|
        pdf.text_box 'A test text', at: [0, 170]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This code generates a pdf file in `public/pdf` folder. What I need, is to be able to download the file right after generation. I tried to download the file, adding this right after the end of `pdf` block of `generate_pdf` method:

```
send_data(filename: pdf, type: 'public/pdf')
```

But it seems, that `send_data` works only in the controller. So, is there a way to download it somehow from the model? Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send file from the model. The controller makes the model data available to the response. The controller should be able to get the generated file from the model and send it to the user.

It can be achieved like this:

```
# controller
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # ...
    @order.save
    send_data(@order.pdf.render, type: 'application/pdf')
  end
end

# model
require 'prawn'

class Order < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :pdf

  after_save :generate_pdf

  def generate_pdf
      if payment_method.name == 'Invoice'
        pdf = Prawn::Document.generate("public/pdf/invoice_#{SecureRandom.hex}_#{user.name}_№#{id}.pdf",
                               page_size: [200, 500],
                               page_layout: :landscape,
                               margin: 10) do |pdf|
        pdf.text_box 'A test text', at: [0, 170]

        self.pdf = pdf
      end
    end
  end
end
```